# PSPDFKit Linker error when creating a category

Tags: ios, clang, linker-errors, pspdfkit

I am working on a project with the `PSPDFKit` demo version. Everything was good until i tried to create a category of `PSPDFDocument`. Since, i have the following linker error :

> ld: section __objc_const (address=0x00F5A7B0, size=4651223840) would
>   make the output executable exceed available address range for
>   architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

Did someone already faced this issue ?

**EDIT :** This seems to appear only when working with Simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the main developer of PSPDFKit.

It took us quite a long time to track down this particular rare bug, and it turned out to be a linker bug in Apple's LLVM toolchain. We've since then reported it and worked around the issue, try any current v3 build and you will not see this bug again.

This has been fixed for a few weeks now.